# Syntactical Golang error with func

Tags: go

Why does the code below throw unexpected func error ? I see error ./func_correct.go:4: syntax error: unexpected func, expecting name

```
package main

func (st  *Stack)  Pop() int {
        v := 0
        for ix := len (st) - 1; ix >= 0; ix-- {
                if v = st[ix]; v != 0 {
                    st[ix] = 0
                    return v
                }
        }
        return 0
}

func main() {
   Pop()    
}
```

Comment: [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and more specifically, show the definition of Stack.

Comment: please show the whole code.

Comment: That's all there to it. I'm learning go and just trying an exercise from chapter 6 of Way to Go.

Comment: OK, the first issue is that you need to define the `Stack` type.  If Way to Go is on the web, then please share a link.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't available online. I think I got the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. define `Stack` type
2. in `main` create a variable of it
3. call `Pop` on it

code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Stack []int

func (st Stack) Pop() int {
    v := 0
    for ix := len(st) - 1; ix >= 0; ix-- {
        if v = st[ix]; v != 0 {
            st[ix] = 0
            return v
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    s := Stack{1, 2, 3, 4}
    i := s.Pop()
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PSac-C0xJM